# Cloudwatch Alarm to Slack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I'm pretty new to AWS but I did some research about my issue and I couldn't find an answer anywhere so hopefully someone can help me with this.

I would like to be notified on Slack whenever someone logs in with a Root account on any of my AWS accounts. I have set up Cloudtrail at the Organisation level to monitor cloudtrail logs on all my AWS account. I have set up a Cloudwatch alarm to trigger whenever a root account is used, the alarm is then sent to a SNS topic that sends it to a Lambda that triggers a message to Slack.

All of this is working fine. However, the message I receive from SNS is basically the following: ***The alarm (root_login) has been trigerred***

Ideally I would want to receive the Cloudwatch event that shows me more information like the IP Address of the user, the AWS account where it occured, etc...

Basically I would like to receive the Cloudwatch event log to the lambda instead of the Cloudwatch alarm trigger. Is that something that is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Relevant?  
https://nivleshc.wordpress.com/2021/06/27/use-aws-lambda-to-send-slack-notifications-for-running-amazon-ec2-instances/

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. [Here](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/us-east-1/641494176294/aws-sns-to-slack-publisher) are some instructions from the AWS site on the `aws-sns-to-slack-publisher`. The page contains the steps you need to take to deploy .

[Here](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:641494176294:applications%7Eaws-health-event-to-slack-message) is an example of publishing a health event to slack.

You will ofcourse need to modify the code to meet your requirements.